# Is there a specific name for diagonally braced truss members like those on the Queensboro Bridge?

Tags: structural-engineering, structures, steel, bridges

[image]

I am wondering about this specific type of truss in particular, any links to further source information and images regarding this particular geometry would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of names for these, but they all have a similar theme:

- Laced strut/tie
- Lattice or Batten bracing
- Lattice truss
- [Lattice Girder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_girder)

I'm sure you get the idea. These were popular in the 19th/early 20th Century before the development of more efficient/cost effective structural sections such as [Structural Hollow Sections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_structural_section), castellated beams, etc.

One paper which discusses the analysis of such elements is available [here](https://www.istructe.org/journal/volumes/volume-30-(published-in-1952)/issues/issue-5/articles/a-theory-for-struts-with-lattice-or-batten-bracing).

Answer (score 0):

Trusses, struts, braces...

The engineering question is usually is it in tension or compression .

As for examples you could check out roofing designs as well as some of the old wooden ships - in some countries ship builders did roofs : all they did was invert the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Quadrangular Trough Warren.

I googled "names for truss frame configurations" for you: https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/f7/3a/8c/f73a8c855f1f4669903fe9d866ddc0d8.jpg